# Swift: Typecast an Object to Other Object

Tags: ios, swift

I created an extension of UIView to add UIToolbar on UIKeyboard for UITextField/UITextView.

```
extension UIView {

    public func addDoneOnKeyboardWithTarget (target : AnyObject, action : Selector) {

        //Creating UIToolbar
        var toolbar = UIToolbar()

        //Configuring toolbar
        var items = NSMutableArray()
        var nilButton = IQBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        items.addObject(nilButton)
        var doneButton = IQBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: target, action: doneAction)
        items.addObject(doneButton)
        toolbar.items = items

        //Now typecasting self to UITextField for compilation purposes because `inputAccessoryView` is readonly for UIView. it's readwrite for UITextField and UITextView both.
        var textField : UITextField = self as UITextField   //Runtime error for UITextView

        //Setting new toolbar as inputAccessoryView
        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    }
}
```

It works fine for UITextField, however when I call the above function on UITextView it crashes on typecasting.

---

Try 1:
I tried it to convert it to Optional

```
var textField : UITextField? = self as? UITextField
textField?.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
```

Now it doesn't crashes on UITextView but also doesn't set any inputAccessoryView on it. When I tried to print it. it prints `nil` on console.

```
println(textField?.inputAccessoryView)  //It prints 'nil'
```

---

Try 2:
I tried it to convert to AnyObject

```
var textField : AnyObject = self as AnyObject
textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar  //Compile time error
```

---

If I replace UITextField to UITextView then obviously it works fine for UITextView but not for UITextField.

Any suggestions?

Comment: a textview is no textfield and a any object has no method inputAccessoryView -- swift enforces type safety

Comment: Yes I know, but how should I overcome for the above issue. I'm converting my open source library to swift https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/blob/master/IQKeyBoardManager/IQUIView%2BIQKeyboardToolbar.m   See line 175

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to 1 a textview is no textfield
to 2 a any object has no method inputAccessoryView
-->> swift enforces type safety

so you can't just cast objects to something they are not

**BUT**

from docs:
"The UIResponder class declares two properties for input views and input accessory views:
@property (readonly, retain) UIView *inputView;
@property (readonly, retain) UIView *inputAccessoryView;"

**BUT it is readonly there**

---

so check the class

```
    var xy:AnyObject!;

    if(xy.isKindOfClass(UITextField)) {
        var t = xy as UITextField;
        //...
    }
    else if(xy.isKindOfClass(UITextView)) {
        var t = xy as UITextView;
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, but UIResponder declared them as readonly. I'm unable to overcome from this problem. I created extension on UIView because it comes in UITextField and UITextView class hierarchy. For UIView these properties are still readonly.

Comment: edited with a short if to switch based on class [untested, but should]

Comment: It Works, but How to check if my instance responds to `setInputAccessoryView:` then call `setInputAccessoryView:` this method?

Comment: if the instance inherits from either TextField or view then it works -- else you would have to create an interface that you can implement and use as a type

Answer (score 2):

**In Swift**, you can use the `type check` operator (`is`) to check whether an instance is of a certain subclass type. The type check operator `returns true` if the instance is of that subclass type and `false` if it is not.

```
 let aViewInstance : UIView = UITextView()

 if aViewInstance is UITextField
 {
     // here, aViewInstance must be an instance of UITextField class & can't be nil
     print(aViewInstance)
     let textField : UITextField = aViewInstance as! UITextField
     print(textField)
 }
 else if aViewInstance is UITextView
 {
     // here, aViewInstance must be an instance of UITextView class & can't be nil
     print(aViewInstance)
     let textView : UITextView = aViewInstance as! UITextView
     print(textView)
 }
 else
 {
     print(" other object ")
 }
```

So you don't need to check `subclass type`, using `isKindOfClass` Method of  `NSObject` class in **Swift** because `isKindOfClass` Method is available only in  NSObject and it's subclasses (all **Objective-C** classes). and In **Swift**, it is possible to create a class without base class or super class.
For Example -

```
 class BaseClass { 
 //properties and methods
 }

 let anObject : AnyObject = BaseClass()

 if anObject is BaseClass {
    print(anObject) // here, must be an instance of BaseClass, you can use it
 } else {
    print(" other object ")
 }
```